# How to take two images within the camera app

Tags: ios, camera

I'm pretty new to this kind of coding but have learnt a fair bit and have unfortunately hit a bump in an app I'm working on.

I am trying to create a camera application that will allow the user to take a 'before' image, then take an 'after' image, I would then like the option for the images to be put together (left and right) and saved as one image.

So far I have managed to code the app to take a single picture with the code below:

HEADER:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,         UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *beforeImage;

- (IBAction)cameraBeforeImage:(UIButton *)sender;

- (IBAction)libraryBeforeImage:(UIButton *)sender;

- (IBAction)deleteBeforeImage:(UIButton *)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *afterImage;

- (IBAction)cameraAfterImage:(UIButton *)sender;

- (IBAction)libraryAfterImage:(UIButton *)sender;

- (IBAction)deleteAfterImage:(UIButton *)sender;

- (IBAction)saveImages:(UIButton *)sender;
@end
```

IMPLEMENTATION:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];
 }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)cameraBeforeImage:(UIButton *)sender {

if (![UIImagePickerController     isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    
    UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!"
                                                          message:@"This Device Has No  Camera, Please Select An Image From Your Library."
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles: nil];
    
    [myAlertView show];
    
}else{

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

}

- (IBAction)libraryBeforeImage:(UIButton *)sender {

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (IBAction)deleteAfterImage:(UIButton *)sender {
}

- (IBAction)saveImages:(UIButton *)sender {
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
self.beforeImage.image = chosenImage;

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (IBAction)deleteBeforeImage:(UIButton *)sender {
}
- (IBAction)cameraAfterImage:(UIButton *)sender {
}

- (IBAction)libraryAfterImage:(UIButton *)sender {
}

- (IBAction)saveImages:(UIButton *)sender {
}


@end
```

Here is the list of things I need to add:

- Add the same functionality to the 'After' buttons as the 'Before' but to store the image in the 'afterImage' Image view.
- Add functionality to the 'saveImages' button to save the two taken images as one image stitched together.

Answer (score 0):

1 . The first problem, I guess you question is 'How do you know which picture was taken and where to display it'?

Answer1: Create two UIImagePickerControllers as properties. Once `imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` returns an image you can simply check which controller was it `if( picker == afterPictureController){...`.

Answer2: Create a flag indicating whether the next taken picture will be an after or a before picture. It's not very flexible but it works.

2 . To stitch two images, you can create UIGraphicsBeginImageContext with size(image1Width+image2Width, MAX(image1Height, image2Height)) and draw image using the context. After that, you can get the stitched image from the context by calling `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();`